# Error when I run "npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli gulp" command line

Tags: npm, yeoman

I get this error when I run the command "npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli gulp".
Does any one know what the problem is?

---

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/??????/.npm/grunt-cli/0.1.13/package.tgz   
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/??????/.npm/yo/1.4.7/package.tgz   
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/??????/.npm/gulp/3.9.0/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/??????/.npm/bower/1.4.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 14.3.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo" "bower" "grunt-cli" 
"gulp"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack:
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)' ] }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/??????/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: One option to resolve the issue is executing the command as `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

As Vohuman pointed out, running this as sudo would fix it. You're trying to install the packages globally which requires access to `/usr/local` which you don't have write privileges to, so as the error message says, `please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

Even "logged in" as root (sudo su) [ On CentOS ]

```
sudo npm install -g ...
```

Otherwise was still executing as user, possibly the directory owner?